# Sitecore Placeholder

Tags: sitecore, placeholder

I have really basic question about placeholder.

In placeholder item, I can see "Description" field. What is this for? I added dump text, but couldn't see any differences in page editor.

I also couldn't find any information regarding this "Description" field.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I could not find much information on the *Description* field either or see anywhere  the field was used.

From Mark Stiles blog :-

> The Description field appears to be informational. I didn't find any
>   place where it was visible other than on the control itself.

https://markstiles.net/Blog/2013/09/27/Designing-a-Page-Editor-Experience-3-Placeholder-Settings.aspx

Comment: In the john west's - sitecore professional book it states 

`Description -- Information relevant to the users interested in
binding controls to the placeholder, which can include a graphic that
indicates the location of the placeholder on the page.`

Binding refers to the person adding rendering to the page in page editor but just checking myself and triple checking doesn't seem to output anything that's useful. I'd call it a redundant field that sitecore should remove or fix if it should be used.

Comment: I also thought this field is supposed to show in placeholder location instead of gray empty places.